# Discrepancy in active usage Fabric vs Firebase

Tags: google-bigquery, firebase-analytics, google-fabric

For an Android application, I am tracking active usage on both Fabric and Firebase. Since the most recent release I am noticing significant discrepancies between the number of daily active users.

From the Fabric docs I understand that active usage is defined as:

> The number of unique app installations across all devices that were
>   active on a specific day. Note: Foreground activity must happen for a
>   device to be active.

Firebase groups active users based on user engagement with a minimal session duration of X seconds (typically 10 secs):

> An active user has engaged with an app in the device foreground, and
>   has logged a user_engagement event.

A possible reason for the discrepancy could be that firebase triggers a `first_open` event when an app is updated which would mean that users are added that have only updated but not engaged with the app.

However, looking at `user_engagement` and `first_open` in bigquery
I can see that they provide different estimates (`user_engagement` exceeding `first_open` events). In this case filtering on `user_engagement` is equal to the number of active users in the firebase dashboard.

Did anybody experience similar discrepancies? I have had contact with both Firebase and Fabric but this did not resolve my issue. Importantly, it is not within a small margin of error, Firebase active users are 4-5 times bigger compared to Fabric.

Comment: We also have discrepancies, but not that big. Is it possible that fabric is tracking application versions without Firebase implemented? I.e did you implement fabric in your app before you implemented Firebase.

Comment: We indeed have Fabric implemented before Firebase. Do you mean that Fabric only tracks application versions w/ no Firebase setup (i.e. misses a proportion of the users)? Intuitively I would say Fabric nrs would be higher because of this while its the other way round.

Comment: No, I thought that Fabric numbers were higher. Then I have no idea. You should probably edit your question, it currently says "Firebase users > Firebase users".

Comment: Ah my bad, edited it right away, thanks!